# How to get buttons above grid?

Tags: wpf

So when designing my buttons are visible when I enter them like this. However, when i run the application they're under the grid layout and it's impossible to see them or use them. How can I get them to show and be usable? Thank you

```
<Window x:Class="Berichtensysteem.Window1"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Berichtensysteem"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="Mailclient" Height="auto" Width="auto"
            >

        <Grid Height="400" Width="600">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="67*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="119*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,-25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="196,-25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
            <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
                <TabItem Header="Inbox" Height="30">
                    <TabItem.Content>
                        <ListView  Name="inbox" BorderThickness="2">
                            <ListView.View >
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Van" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Onderwerp" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Op" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </TabItem.Content>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Verzonden items" Height="30">
                    <TabItem.Content>
                        <ListView  Name="sentitems" BorderThickness="2">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="From" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Op" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </TabItem.Content>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Verwijderde Items" Height="30"
                         >
                    <TabItem.Content>
                        <ListView  Name="deleteditems" BorderThickness="2">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="From" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Op" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </TabItem.Content>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>

    </Window>
```

Edit: my buttons do show when i resize the window to fullscreen. So it might have something to do with my code:

```
        //Resize to fit content
        this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
```

However if I don't use the above my window doesn't look as neat because there's a lot of whitespace.

Comment: Runs flawless on Win10. Consider adding 2 rows. One for the buttons in row 0 and one for the TabControl in Row 1

Comment: UIElements are laid out in the order they are introduced in the xaml. If they overlap, the later elements will be on the top of the ones that were previously defined.

Otherwise I'd suggest a code review, the design is "interesting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. Notice the 2 Rows i've added. Feel free to customize the `StackPanel` as it fits your needs.

```
<Grid Height="400" Width="600">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="67*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="119*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        </StackPanel>

        <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">
            <TabItem Header="Inbox" Height="30">
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <ListView  Name="inbox" BorderThickness="2">
                        <ListView.View >
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Van" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Onderwerp" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Op" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Verzonden items" Height="30">
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <ListView  Name="sentitems" BorderThickness="2">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="From" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Op" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Verwijderde Items" Height="30"
                         >
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <ListView  Name="deleteditems" BorderThickness="2">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="From" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Op" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

**Result**

[image: OutputImage]

Comment: Why do you need the ColumnDefinitions?

Comment: Not my Question. Just my answer based on OP's question

Comment: @user3227070 It **does** work. even with `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`

Comment: I think it is not the awaited answer. OP seems to want the buttons in front of the grid and not above the grid. Otherwise, your answer is correct if OP wants to have buttons above the grid (as in Y-axis).

Comment: @EtienneFaucher You mean in a Layer above Grid?

Comment: I mean like Z-axis, yes. Two buttons in front of the grid, not above the grid.

Comment: @EtienneFaucher Wow... i believe you are right. Well hard to guess what OP wants

Comment: @EtienneFaucher I had to move my tabcontrol down because they were stacked on top of eachother, thats why it appeared not to work. Fixed now, thank you